# Using the Lyapunov-Perron method to find the local stable/unstable manifolds

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds

Hello Stack Exchange community.  I am currently having an issue finding the local stable/unstable manifolds of this system.  After going at it for a few hours I believe the person who wrote this problem made a mistake as I am unable to find a stable/unstable manifold at $(0,0)$ of the system..

System:

- $X' = -X + Y + 3Y^2 $
- $Y' = Y$
- Eigenvalues: $-1, 1$
- Stable Eigenvalues: $-1$
- Unstable Eigenvalues: $1$
- Nonlinear Part: $3Y^2$

After using the Lyapunov-Peron method (https://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/wiki/images/b/ba/Cds140a-wi11-Week4Notes.pdf) and iterating 3 times, I am unable to find an actual stable manifold of degree 2 or 3.

- $X_0 = (0,0)$
- $X_1 = (e^{-t},0)$ (first iteration)
- $X_2 = (e^{-t},0)$ (second iteration)
- $X_3 = (e^{-t},0)$ (third iteration)

The stable and unstable aspect of the iterative method keep going to $0$ as the unstable part is $0$ as the nonlinear part of the $Y'$ equation is $0$.

That being said the nonlinear part of the $X'$ equation ($X' = -X + Y + 3Y^2$) becomes $0$ as it relies on the previous iteration.  The previous iteration $(e^{-t},0)$ makes it $0$ as the $y$ vector is $0$ and the $x$ is $e^{-t}$.

For the $y$ vector of the previous iteration do I just directly plug in the solution of the $Y'$ ODE, i.e. $e^t$?

P.S. Sorry if it is a bit messy. I have never used Latex before.

Comment: Did you try to write down explicitly $(x(t),y(t))$ in terms of $t$ and of the position $(x_0,y_0)$ at time $0$ (just what they do in the notes)? Then the answer is clear...

Comment: I will.  However, one couldnt find the answer by using the Lyapunov-Peron method as well?

Comment: Where is this method even mentioned in the text you link to?

Comment: The method is mentioned in section 1.2.1 of that text I linked.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the name Lyapunov-Perron does not appear in this section.

Comment: The name "Lyapunov-Perron" is the name used that an instructor a few semesters used.  I am just trying to beef up on it as one of my classes this semester is using this theory and its been awhile.  That being said, is my assumption about the manifolds(local stable/unstable) not existing, correct?  Even when I use your method of directly computing the solutions to the nonlinear system, I still get the manifolds being zero as I set "t = 0" and then for the system to equal zero.

Comment: Not "my" method, but the one your handout shows. What is the solution $(x(t),y(t))$ you found?